# Remove standalone from xml

Tags: java, tomcat, jaxb

I have some problems with removing of standalone from xml header. I tried:

```
 marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlDeclaration", Boolean.TRUE);
 marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
```